# Setting an input to its most recent valid value

Tags: javascript, html, validation, polyfills

I'm trying to write a polyfill for HTML5's `input type="number"` element. [Here's a comparative example](http://jsfiddle.net/gFgAT/) if your browser already supports it.

If you enter a value that cannot be parsed as a number, such as "abc", when you blur, Chrome will set the value back to whatever the most recent valid value you was. I suppose I could do that by storing the value in a `data-` attribute whenever the field gets focus, just in case I need to set it back, but is there any more natural way to go about "remembering" the most recent valid value a form field had?

Answer (score 0):

This is often called **undo**. [This fellow](https://dbebek.wordpress.com/javascript/undo-input-textbox-change-using-javascript/) shows you how to do it with JavaScript:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         function InputBalance_OnChange(sender) {
            if(isNaN(sender.value)) {
               sender.value = isNaN(sender.prevValue) ? 0 : sender.prevValue;
            } else {
               sender.prevValue = sender.value;
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Account Number</td>
            <td><input id="inputAccountNumber" type="text" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Balance</td>
            <td><input id="inputBalance" type="text" onChange="InputBalance_OnChange(this)" value="0" /></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. The `prevValue` property appears to be for attribute modification, and doesn't appear to be a property of the types of events I'm dealing with.